# Cropping an image taken from AVCaptureStillImageOutput

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image, ios7

I am trying to crop an image taken from AVCaptureStillImageOutput but unable to properly crop at the correct rectangles.

My preview of camera video is 320x458 frame and the cropping rectangle is present inside this preview frame which has the co-ordinates and size as CGRectMake(60, 20, 200, 420).

After taking the picture, I receive the image from

```
NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
UIImage *finalImage = [self cropImage:image];
```

Afterwards I am trying to crop this actual image of size 1080x1920 with the below function. I am getting a wayward clipping and the resultant image is way out of the actual rectangle! ;(

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)oldImage {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(60, 20, 200, 420);
    CGSize boundSize = CGSizeMake(320, 458);

    float widthFactor = rect.size.width * (oldImage.size.width/boundSize.width);
    float heightFactor = rect.size.height * (oldImage.size.height/boundSize.height);
    float factorX = rect.origin.x * (oldImage.size.width/boundSize.width);
    float factorY = rect.origin.y * (oldImage.size.height/boundSize.height);

    CGRect factoredRect = CGRectMake(factorX,factorY,widthFactor,heightFactor);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([oldImage CGImage], factoredRect) scale:oldImage.scale orientation:oldImage.imageOrientation];
    return croppedImage;
}
```

In the attached picture, I am trying to crop the coffee mug, but what I get is not the correct cropped image!

[image: Image to be cropped]
[image: Cropped image - wrong]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use PEPhotoCropEditor sample code for cropping. It's easy to use. you can download source code from https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pephotocropeditor

Answer (score 0):

i am also facing hard time in this i think the what you have to do is write image of file then crop that image or try out orientation issue to solve.